# How to iterate over a multi-document YAML file to pipe to a command?

Tags: bash, kubernetes, yaml

I have a command that generates a secrets file that contains multiple `yaml` documents separated by `---` that looks like the following output:

```
## THE COMMAND THAT RUNS
kubectl kustomize .

## SENDS THE FOLLOWING TO STDOUT
data:
  firebase-dev-credentials.json: |
    MY_BASE_64_CREDENTIALS
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: nodejs-firebase-credentials-989t6dg7m2
type: Opaque
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  AGENDA_DATABASE_URL: |
    MY_BASE_64_URL
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: nodejs-secrets-c229fkh579
type: Opaque
```

Now, I have to pipe the `yaml` document to another command for processing, something like:

`kubectl kustomize . | kubeseal`

However, the `kubeseal` command does not accept multi-document `yaml`. So I figured I'd need to split the `yaml` by `---` and send each individual document to the `kubeseal` command?

Using `bash`, what is the preferred approach to accomplish this task?

For example, I suppose I cannot do something simple like this as the `stdout` is multiline?

```
export IFS=";"
sentence="one;two;three"
for word in $sentence; do
  echo "$word"
done
```

Comment: `for item in $string` is itself malpractice, for largely the reasons [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) gives for not iterating over `ls` or `find` given the same syntax. Only arrays should be iterated over -- relying on string splitting also invokes glob expansion. Mind, you can certainly insert your documents into an array, if you wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe through `yq eval 'select(di == N)'` to select out document N. But really, you wouldn't do this. You would include the already sealed data in your Kustomize config, it's not something you want to run automatically.

Comment: I see ok, so instead of using kustomize's `secretGenerator` feature to create secret yaml's, you're suggesting, to create the sealed secrets beforehand and simply add them as `resources` in the `kustomization.yaml` instead?

Comment: That is correct, the whole reason to use sealed secrets is so you can commit the encrypted form to source control safely. Which means that needs to be the actual thing on disk.

Comment: Yea! I still plan to store in source control. The goal was to pipe out from the `kubeseal` command the sealed secrets to store in SC. But the issue I had was looping each individual secret since `kubeseal` doesn't allow multiple secrets in a YAML file :/

Comment: Yeah, it's an annoyance once the first time when you set stuff up but afterwards not so bad. I just broke them out into files by hand when I did it long ago :)

Answer (score 0):

If parsing with `bash` only,

```
x="$(kubectl kustomize .)"
while [[ -n "$x" ]]
do ary+=("${x%%---*}")
if [[ "$x" =~ --- ]]; then x="${x#*---}"; else x=''; fi
done
for yml in "${ary[@]}"; do kubeseal<<<"$yml"; done
```

Answer (score -1):

Es every so often, there might be different solutions, but one way is:

```
IFS="" # retain front tabs
buf=""
while read line
do
    if [ "$line" == "---" ]
    then
        echo -e $buf | kubeseal
        buf=""
    else
        if [ "$buf" == "" ] # prevent empty first newline
        then
            buf="$line"
        else
            buf=$(echo "$buf\\n$line")
        fi
    fi
done < yml

# get last section
echo -e $buf | kubeseal
```

Comment: With `echo -e $buf` this is replacing a `*` (albeit strictly when it's the only input in a line, since you cleared IFS) with a list of filenames in the current directory, and replacing the two-character sequence `\n` with a single-character newline; none of that is desirable behavior.

Comment: Also, add the `-r` argument to `read` so you don't eat literal backslashes in the input.

Comment: Really, though `echo` should be removed entirely and replaced with `printf` to avoid munging the input on its way back out; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113 -- even when the shell is 100% certain to be bash, both compiletime and (environment-inheritable) runtime flags can make `echo -e ` print `-e` on output; and several more strictly POSIX-compliant shells behave that way out-of-the-box.

Comment: `buf="$buf"$'\n'"$line"`, for example, will append `$line` to `$buf` without the need for a command substitution (thus the considerable performance hit of forking off a subshell); but it would be even more efficiently written as `buf+=$'\n'"$line"`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the detailed, explanatory feedback!